# How to make responsive banner in vegas slider

Tags: css

i already add css for responsive banner vegas slider for my portal. The problem is the recommended size for the banner is 1800X600px and it display nicely in 1280X1024 of monitor resolution but the banner will be stretched and the banner look ugly in 1860X1020 of monitor resolution. If i view it via mobile phone, the banner will be squeeze to fit the screen. Below is the css that i add.

```
.vegas-slide-inner {
    background-size:100% 100% !important;
}
```

Is there any other way to make the banner fit in any resolution of display?

Comment: can u add a  preview !

Comment: you can go to https://www.yp.com.kh/ and look at the first image of the slider. My concern is the yellow book in my image.

Comment: i suggest to change a responsive slider this is an example : http://pgwjs.com/pgwslider/

Answer (score 0):

Use cover instead of giving it 100%
`background-size: cover;`

Comment: hi Anmol, i've try your method but it seems doesn't work.

Comment: Hello Iqmal, i see background-size: 100% is overriding cover. I think you should apply bakground-size: cover !important. It will work definately